# Why would sending an email via php from one domain to an email on the same domain is being blocked

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am having the weirdest issue, I have a website with a contact form, I am using php `mail()` to process the form and send the email. The issue is that the email is never receiving the message sent from the website. The email is on the same domain name as the site that is sending it. Also I have put in other email addresses and the form works fine. I have also sent directly from my gmail account to the email account that isn't receiving from the website and everything works fine.

It appears that only emails being sent from the website are being blocked. I have checked the spam filter, white listed the email, and called the server company who checked everything to see if the message was getting caught somewhere and after an hour on the phone with them they can not identify the issue either.

I have exhausted every means, I have implemented PHPMailer and that still did not go through. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have exhausted every possible means to ensure that I am doing things right and nothing has worked.

This is the page where the form is:
http://ownerbuilderloans.com/contact-us

This is the email address its sending to:
loans @ ownerbuilderloans.com

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: what do the mail logs say ?

Comment: @Dagon Honestly I'm not sure if I can check them, the domain is being hosted on media temple and them email is being handled by Synergy Broadband and I'm not sure how to check the logs.

Comment: i don't know how any one debugs anything with access to the appropriate log files.

Comment: @Dagon Would the logs show anything, I'm using php's mail() method, so its not actually routed through the email address itself?

Comment: the mail server logs would be most useful, mail() uses the local mail server. as you have used PHPMailer why not try another mailserver, such as Gmails, just to test with

Answer (score 2):

You have to talk to whoever runs the mail server you are sending mail to. They must analyze the problem. If they're unwilling or unable to do so, get another provider to do your mail services. Access to the mail server's logs are needed. Someone with access to those logs has to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I have been talking to the company handling the mail issue and we checked to ensure the email address was not black listed, we white listed it spent an hour on the phone until he gave up and said he would have another person contact me more specialized in this area.

Comment: @TomBird What you need to know is what happened to the emails that didn't get delivered. The operator of the mail server you sent the emails to should be able to tell you whether they were accepted by another mail server or not.